# Is there a benefit in assigning the last enum value in a list as -1?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I've seen it in coding conventions at previous/current job(s), but I can't seem to find a reason online for why this would be the preferred way of writing an enum:

```
enum class Mode
{
    Mode1,
    Mode2,
    Mode3,
    Mode4,
    Nil = -1
};
```

What (if any) is the benefit of adding the `Nil = -1` line?

Comment: I assume `Nil` has a special meaning in those programs. If all other `Mode`s affect the _mode_ of something, presumably `Nil` doesn't. Check in the code what it's used for. It should be obvious.

Comment: I've never seen this convention before. I guess `Nil` will always be different from other enum values, while still being defined at the bottom. Maybe your organisation has some sort of `is_nil` function for enums that checks for enum values less than zero. You would be better off asking whoever authored the convention or whoever presented it to you. Usually, conventions should include the reasoning behind the rules.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I should probably preface that I haven't seen the `Nil` naming at other jobs for this particular thing, but I have seen creating some term at the end and giving it distinct value like -1

Comment: @TylerKelly you can still [edit] your question with whatever preface you think is appropriate.  From your last comment - it seem like the `-1` enum is familiar to you, but the name `Nil` is what you are asking about.  Is that correct?

Comment: From an `enum` perspective, it doesn't matter if the `Nil` is at the bottom of the list, at the top of the list, or in the middle (other than appropriately resuming the enumeration value for the subsequent enumeration identifier).  Why the `Nil` is there at all... for that you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: @DrewDormann while I've seen it often, my main question is why its a -1, the `Nil` naming scheme is superfluous to me

Comment: It is a stylistic choice.  It's not `-1` because it's the last enum.  It's `-1` because it's considered a _"special value"_, and it shouldn't change if a `Mode5` were added, or if `Mode4` were removed.  It signifies that `Nil` is intended to be considered separate from the other enum values.  It could be listed first, and it could be `-2`.  The only intention is to separate it from the other "0, counting upward" values.

Comment: I used to add `Last, First = Mode1` for some extra controls and generalize iteration code, but somewhere in the last 10 years-or-so I stopped doing it. Not sure why.